# Number of possible passwords with certain constraints

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

If I require a password of length 8 to have at least 2 numbers, 2 uppercase letters and the rest lowercase and I absolutely need the letter A in my password, the number of possibilities would be as follow:
$$ number \cdot number \cdot A \cdot uppercase \cdot lowercase \cdot lowercase \cdot lowercase \cdot lowercase$$
which would result in:
$$10^2 \cdot 1 \cdot 26^5$$ possibilities.

However, if the last half were to be any type of character, whether it be number, uppercase or lowercase and we have the same approach, a problem occurs.
Would you count the 'A' as part of the uppercases or the all-type character? To illustrate:
$$ number \cdot number \cdot A \cdot uppercase \cdot lowercase \cdot lowercase \cdot lowercase \cdot lowercase = 10^2 \cdot 1 \cdot 26^5 $$is different from
$$ number \cdot number \cdot uppercase \cdot uppercase \cdot A \cdot any\cdot any\cdot any= 10^2 \cdot 26^2 \cdot 1 \cdot 62^3.$$
How would I find the number of possibilities that combine both these situations?

Comment: Did same $2$ uppercase letters allow$?$

Comment: Yea u can have duplicates

Comment: If you wish to have *at least* two uppercase letters and *at least* two digits in a password that may include lowercase letters, your initial calculation does not make sense since you would have $26 + 26 + 10 = 64$ choices for each character. You calculated the number of passwords that have digits in the first two positions, an uppercase letter in the third position, an A in the fourth position, and lowercase letters in the remaining positions.

Comment: I don't think your second problem is very clear.

Comment: You seem to be saying that the characters have to appear in a certain order. Is the password `Ba9k2Aem` allowed, or would it need to be like `92ABmake`? If you do not require this order, then your first calculation is incorrect.